# What kind of switching system can I use for a massive array of high-impedance electrodes?

Tags: multiplexer, analog-switch, high-impedance, electrochemical

**My application:** I am attempting to create a device to map redox potential in soils at ~1 mm resolution, using a grid of platinum electrodes.

**Background:** Redox potential is a measure of the "electron pressure" created by the reduced species of chemicals in the soil, and is a general measure of how anaerobic a soil is. It is typically done in the following setup, [illustrated here](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0065211306940012-gr2.jpg): A platinum electrode is inserted in the soil, as is a  reference electrode that uses the Ag/Ag2+ redox couple and which completes a salt bridge with the soil. Both are connected to a high-impedance (~10 GOhm) voltmeter. The high impedance of the voltmeter is very important to the whole setup, because the charge density in the soil is very small and the kinetics of oxidation are slow, so any electron flow from the soil to the reference electrode will cause the voltage to drift. Typical values of redox potential range from +700 mV to -400 mV, and they are essentially DC, changing only over the course of hours.

This setup is all well and good for taking single point measurements in the soil, but I want to be able to map redox potential over a 5 x 5 cm grid (at a resolution of ~1 mm, so 2500 electrodes total, lower resolution acceptable , say 2mm, if 1mm^2 can't be achieved) to explore how heterogeneous redox conditions are over short spatial scales. Because there are so many electrodes, I want to take reasonably fast measurements, say 1 per second.

**My approach:** I've landed on the idea of creating a PCB that has copper pads on one side, and then electroplating the pads with 100 um of platinum, in order to create the grid of electrodes that I can insert into soil. The electrodes would each be connected to the reverse side of the PCB with a via, where I want to implement switching circuitry to route signal to the high-impedance voltmeter, one pixel at a time. (I really want to avoid running 2500 wires to another circuit board for the switching, as I want to use potting compound to insulate the circuit from soil water.)

**My questions:** I'm stuck on how to implement the switching circuitry in a compact fashion that will allow sufficient electrode density. For true microelectrode arrays (e.g. used in neurophysiology), hundreds of electrodes are able to be placed into a square millimeter because they put a 3T CMOS switch array on an IC die. I think that would be the best sort of architecture for this project, where an entire row of electrodes is switched on at one time, with all the electrodes in each column connected to their own bus that goes to ADC circuitry [(see Figure 2 on this page to see what I'm talking about)](https://www.edmundoptics.com/knowledge-center/application-notes/imaging/understanding-camera-sensors-for-machine-vision-applications/) . But the comparatively large size of the electrode array in my case makes this impractical, and anyway I completely lack the money or the knowledge to be able to create my own IC die. (I'm a soil scientist.)

- Is there a way that I can implement this sort of switching system
  using off-the-shelf SMD devices, allowing me to achieve high
  electrode density? (I would pay to have the boards pick-and-place
  fabricated.)
- What sort of switch design would be appropriate for my
  purposes?  To my mind, the key design considerations are ultra-low
  leakage current, both on and off, low stray capacitance (so that the
  voltage doesn't take a long time to stabilize), and a small
  footprint. Are there other important design parameters I should
  consider?
- Does anyone have particular components in mind they could suggest?
- Am I approaching this project completely wrong and there's a much better way to do what I want?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suppose there is no way to do this optically by putting a grid of redox sensitive dyes or fluorophores in a cell and recording brightness with a CMOS image sensor? Otherwise fitting SMD read out electronics into a 1x1 mm square will be very challenging.

Comment: While there are dyes/fluorophores available for specific redox couples, there's no general fluorophore for indicating potential... I looked into this for a bit. I am not opposed to decreasing the resolution, say to 2mm x 2 mm, if necessary, though.

Comment: Also pay attention to the charge injection parameter of the multiplexer ICs. Each switching cycle injects a charge, that must disappear before the ADC can take a sample.

Comment: A fuller description of the electrode head maybe in order. Sample diagram shows an electrode where depth seems a major parameter. How do your 2500 electrodes interface to the soil? - On the surface? With 3D depth? What interelectrode in soil separation etc. || A 16 electrode 4mm x 4mm grid sounds maybe OK for a 16 input multiplexer using "chip on board or maybe TSSOP packaging. || The VERY high impedance may make reed relays attractive. || What multiplexing regime is acceptable and why? - COULD you do 4x4 adjacent grid if electronics allowed. Or every 10oth or 5th in a row, or grid or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to multiplexers I want to suggest the use of OpAmps with output disable or shutdown feature.

They have excellent high input impedance compared to multiplexers and your signal will be buffered directly near the sensor electrode. So the design does not have to be low leakage everywhere.

If you connect the outputs in columns and the enable lines in rows you have a kind of discrete multiplexer.

I had the LMC8101 in mind, the 1.4 mm² BGA style case is not far away from your requirements. MAX4401 using 2.2 mm² may also fit. However, you should test a small grid of them to verify the idea. Especially check if the charge at the input stays the same when the amplifier is turned off.

Ask the manufacturer if 10 GΩ input impedance is possible with this small pitch BGA chips.

You could make a board with the electrodes only and 1 mm pitch pin headers on the other side. There you can plug in vertically mounted boards, one board for two lines of electrodes.

Such a construction gives room for some decorative capacitors and you don't need too many copper layers. If you lose one "pixel" on an ESD accident, you just have to replace one pluggable row.

And finally this is much cheaper than the analog multiplexer solution.

Comment: In order for this to be cheaper, a 28-way mux would need to be 28x (from 2500/89) the price of an op-amp, so I don't think that holds true. The DSBGA package is actually 1.464mm by 1.464mm (not 1.464mm2) , so you couldn't use this with a 1mm array, but you might fit it in with a 2mm. 
Vertically mounted boards on the back probably isn't going to be great for a device that needs to be inserted into soil, and you'd have to have something to collect all the data from the 25 boards in order to process it.

Comment: @LordTeddy Thanks for the hint related to the wrong chip area. I could not find analog multiplexers with >=10 Gohm isolation and low charge injection/capacitance and a large number of switches on Digikey. I am interested in the 28-way mux you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments both of you! Yeah, while I wish it would be feasible to swap out busted components, everything needs to be buried in the soil, and so I think I want something that can be on a single board and covered in potting compound. Same reason why I dont want to run 2500 wires... it needs to be fairly robust to harsh environmental conditions. I like the idea of an op amp a) because I understand op-amps, and the routing would be relatively straightforward and b) I like the idea of only having to worry about current leakage in a small area (minimal PCB design skills)

Comment: It seems like the 1mm^2 idea is not feasible but the 4mm^2 electrode could be made to work with a tiny op amp. Another question, then... do I need an op amp specifically with a shutdown pin, or could I simply ground V+ to turn the op amp off when not making a measurement? Will there be negative effects on my electrode signal if I do so?

Comment: @user278411 turning the supply of will most probably discharge the inputs and the output will be an unknown load on the analog bus.

Comment: Gotcha. OK thanks! This gives me a lot to go off of, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Possible, but very expensive.

Having a 50x50 array of platinum electrodes at 1mm seems reasonable to me, I'll assume you've found a PCB house that can do this and you have the budget to have it made.
 Instead of trying to cram the circuit onto the back of a 5cmx5cm PCB, I can't see why you wouldn't have some of the PCB not inserted into the soil for the electronics. Something like this
[image]

Routing the 2,500 connections is fine if a bit (and by a bit I mean heckin') time-consuming. Then it's just a case of multiplexing the signals and ADCs. Find the widest analog multiplexer (most signals) you can, and place the number you need, if it's 28 channels, you need 89, though perhaps you do two-stage multiplexing to reduce the outputs further. There are some questions like how many ADCs to use, and how to collect the data, how to process the signal for the ADC.  It is very much an application for a FPGA, but even then you might need some additional I/O expansion. There's maths to be done on the sample rate, number of bits, total conversion time, settling of the multiplexing etc.

Totally doable as far as I can initially see if I've understood your requirements. Don't get me wrong though, it would be a monster, tremendously expensive both to design and make and I think I might weep for joy if I ever saw it.